# Set JavaScript countdown to end at midnight PST?

Tags: javascript, timezone, datejs

I am trying to get a countdown to end Monday @ midnight PST. I thought I had it working a week ago but apparently not.

I am using date.js

```
var monday = Date.today().next().monday();
var UTCmonday = new Date(monday.getTime() + monday.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
var PSTmonday = new Date(UTCmonday.setHours(UTCmonday.getHours() + 9));
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: UTCmonday});
```

I think the problem is in determining UTC time? Am I right? How do I work this out?

Comment: Do you need to use the local computer's time? It might be more accurate -- and easier for you -- if you could use a public time service, which could probably give you time in UTC. You make a GET request to the service, and the json response would likely contain a javascript date string.

Comment: PST meaning Pacific Standard Time?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you Pacific Standard Time, then you need to remember that PST === UTC-8

Thus, your third line would be

```
var PSTmonday = new Date(UTCmonday.setHours(UTCmonday.getHours() - 8));
```

The problem with this is that this will fail if the UTC is any earlier than 8am, since you can't pass a negative number into `setHours`.

Since you're using Datejs, why not use its full capabilities for changing the timezone?

http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#setTimezone

Answer (score 0):

Getting the time strictly in PST doesn't make much sense, as for almost half of the year PST isn't observed in the Pacific time zone.  PST (UTC-8) is observed in the winter, and PDT (UTC-7) is observed in the summer.  You can't represent Pacific Time as just a fixed offset, and unless it happens to be your own local time zone, you can't easily determine the transition between them without a time zone database.  See [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Also, [date.js has been abandoned](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/datejs/info).  I can't recommend any solution that continues its use.  Support for the `setTimezone` method that Dancrumb suggested is culture specific, and it still doesn't take daylight saving time into consideration.

Instead, I recommend trying [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).  You can use the [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) add-on to work with the `America/Los_Angeles` zone - which is a good exemplar of US Pacific time.  Make sure your `moment-timezone-data.js` file includes at least this zone.  Then you can do the following:

```
var m = moment().tz('America/Los_Angeles').day(7).startOf('day');

var s = m.toISOString();  // if you need a string output representing UTC
var dt = m.toDate();      // if you need an actual JavaScript Date object
```

Let's break that down a bit:

- `moment()` gets you the current time
- `tz('America/Los_Angeles')` adjusts the time to the timezone you are interested in.
- `day(7)` advances the time to the *next* Monday.
- `startOf('day')` snaps the time back to midnight.